# How to find the index of the minimum value after starting point?

Tags: python

I have a `list = [5,2,3,10,1,10,5,6,5,8,10]`

I want to find the index of the minimum value after a certain point.

For example, if I want to find the index of the minimum value after index 1, then index 1 is 2 which means the minimum value is 1 which is index 4.

I want to code it like `def find_min(lst, index)`, where `lst` is my list and `index` is the starting point.

Explanation needed too.

Answer (score 2):

The function in the format you have asked for

```
def find_min(lst, index):
   list_to_check = lst[index:]  # creating a list list_to_check with only elements starting from given index to last element
   min_value = min(list_to_check)   # found the minimum value in the new list list_to_check
   return (list_to_check.index(min_value)+index) # list_to_check.index(min_value) gives the index of the minimum value in new list list_to_check. Since index from old list is needed, we add it with index
```

Comment: may I ask why do I need to + index at the end?

Comment: Updated my answer with comments @PythonUser428

Answer (score 0):

use min to find out the min, then use the index to get the index

```
values = [5,2,3,10,1,10,5,6,5,8,10]
afterThisPoint = 1
m = values[afterThisPoint+1:].index(min(values[afterThisPoint+1:]))
print(m+afterThisPoint+1)
```

```
4
```

Comment: Is this hard coding? Like specifically for one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the min function on a range of indexes with an indirection to the list for the minimum value.  This will produce the result in a single pass through the data (as opposed to computing the minimum and searching it in the list):

```
def iMinAfter(aList,index):
    return min(range(index+1,len(aList)),key=lambda i:aList[i]) 

myList = [5,2,3,10,1,10,5,6,5,8,10]

print( iMinAfter(myList,1) ) # 4
```